# why tiny mce doesn't work on an online server and it work fine on localhost?

Tags: tinymce

> Hi every one , i have a question about **Tinymce**,
>   why doesn't work on an online server and it work fine on localhost?
>   this is the code i used

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  tinyMCE.init({
  mode : "textareas",
  theme : "advanced",
  directionality: "rtl",
  align:"right",
   // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
  template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
  external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
  external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
  media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

  // Style formats
  style_formats : [
  {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
  {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
  {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
  {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
  {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
  {title : 'Table styles'},
  {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
  ],


  });
 </script>
```

> thanks for help

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately you're not providing enough info. First of all, what's the cause of the failure? Do you use Firebug, or Chrome developer tools? You should specify what the error message is, there's no error like "doesn't work".

Comment: the problem is that i can't get the wyswig editor visible for the textarea,i only get a simple textarea instead,thanks again for help.

Comment: The problem could be caused by many things, for example a different path is used on your server, the relative path to the script may be different, and these can cause your application to search for the JavaScript source of tinyMCE in a wrong place. Also there could be some sort of JavaScript error. You definitely should look at an error console, whatever browser you're testing in, it should have one. If you're not sure how fire it up, just google it, it's not hard. Then clear it, and reload your page, and provide that information here, if it doesn't help you too much.

Comment: thanks barta it was a problem with a path of javascript of tinymce, add me on facebook to exchange experiences

Comment: @AbderrahimWadd: please post your solution as answer(for the sake of others with the same problem) and accept it later

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40199890/4315380) answer can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue ...tried ALL solutions. But now i solve it. So,,, hope this piece of code help others. 
To fix WordPress visual editor not showing, follow the steps below:-

- FTP to your web server
- Download your wp-config.php and add this line of code at the bottom of the file before the “require_once” line.

**define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );**

enjoy sharing !! :)