# Asp.net TinyMCE editor is not showing up online windows server but it works on localhost

Tags: asp.net, tinymce, editor

TinyMCE editor is not showing up after publishing. Though, it works on localhost. Here's what I see:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide `baseURL` to tinyMCE before initialising it. You can do that right before `tinymce.init({...})`. Often, it works on localhost without this but on server it is not able to find the tinymce root directory.

According to [TinyMCE Docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/),

"property: `baseURL`, type: `String`, Description: Base URL where the root directory of TinyMCE is located."

Example:

```
tinyMCE.baseURL = "PATH/TO/tinymce/directory/";

tinyMCE.init({
    theme : "simple",
    ...
});
```

Comment: For IIS be sure to prefix the path with ../ to get to the root.